# React hooks pagination with useEffect - how to revert page number if request fails?

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks

I'm testing out simple paging with react hooks, and wondering how to deal with failures to keep it valid in state?

Pseudo code:

```
function reducer(state, action) {
  switch (action.type) {
    case 'next':
      return {page: state.page + 1};
    case 'prev':
      return {page: state.page - 1};
    default:
      throw new Error();
  }
}

function Page() {
  const [state, dispatch] = useReducer(reducer, { page: 1});

  useEffect(() => {
    loadMore(state.page)
    .then(r => console.log(r))
    .catch(e => {
      // how to revert page without triggering this effect?
      // cause if I do dispatch({type: 'prev'}) page will change, and this will re-run
      console.log(e)
    })
  }, state.page)

  return (
    <>
      Page: {state.page}
      <button onClick={() => dispatch({type: 'prev'})}>-</button>
      <button onClick={() => dispatch({type: 'next'})}>+</button>
    </>
  );
}
```

Let's take this scenario:

- we start with page 1
- user clicks next
- page is increased in state
- useEffect fires, network request fails.
- page in state is 2, but actual data is of page 1

I cannot dispatch page change event on catch, because it would trigger refetch, which I don't want to do

Another option about which I was thinking was that I should maybe increment page only after I've got the data for it, but then I would create infinite loop in useEffect cause page would change after fetching data?

Answer (score 2):

You can also simply **remove `useEffect`** and use such function instead:

```
let fetch = (page, isNext)=>{

 loadMore(page)
    .then(r => {
      // ..
      isNext ? dispatch({type: 'next'}):dispatch({type: 'prev'});
    })
    .catch(e => {
      // Don't dispatch anything, you will remain on same page
    })

}
```

Now when user clicks next, just call that `fetch(state.page + 1, true)`. If she clicks prev btn, use `fetch(state.page - 1, false)`;

Comment: Simple solution for prev/next paging. But what if I need to call fetch from another useEffect (e.g. infite scroll) - then afaik same issues remain

Comment: @gerasalus can't you omit useEffect in that infinite scroll scenario too?

Answer (score 0):

You could add another piece of state representing the page we'd like to see, assuming it loads.

```
function reducer(state, action) {
  switch (action.type) {
    case 'failed':
      return { ...state, requestedPage: null };
    case 'loaded':
      return { page: action.page, requestedPage: null };
    case 'next':
      return { ...state, requestedPage: state.page + 1 };
    case 'prev':
      return { ...state, requestedPage: state.page - 1 };
    default:
      throw new Error();
  }
}

const Page = () => {
  const [{ page, requestedPage }, dispatch] = useReducer(reducer, {
    page: 1,
    requestedPage: null,
  });

  useEffect(() => {
    loadMore(requestedPage)
      .then((r) => {
        dispatch({ type: 'loaded', page: requestedPage });
        console.log(r);
      })
      .catch((e) => {
        dispatch({ type: 'failed' });
        console.error(e);
      });
    // Make sure the dependencies are an array
  }, [requestedPage]);

  // Optimistically render the requestedPage (with a spinner?) if present,
  // otherwise current page.
  return (
    <>
      Page: {requestedPage || page}
      <button onClick={() => dispatch({ type: 'prev' })}>-</button>
      <button onClick={() => dispatch({ type: 'next' })}>+</button>
    </>
  );
};
```

Answer (score 0):

I would use `useRef()` to preserve the previous page on success. If the current call fails, go back to the previous page by setting it. When entering `useEffect()`, check if the current page, and the page stored in the ref are the same, and do nothing if they are.

```
function reducer(state, { type, page }) {
  switch (type) {
    case 'set':
      return { page };
    case 'next':
      return { page: state.page + 1 };
    case 'prev':
      return { page: state.page - 1 };
    default:
      throw new Error();
  }
}

function Page() {
  const [state, dispatch] = useReducer(reducer, { page: 1 });

  const currentPage = useRef();

  useEffect(() => {
    if (currentPage.current === state.page) return;

    loadMore(state.page)
    .then(r => {
      currentPage.current = state.page;
    })
    .catch(e => {
      dispatch({ type: 'set', page: currentPage.current || 1 }); // if currentPage.current doesn't exist use page 1 as default

      console.log(e)
    })
  }, state.page)

  return (
    <>
      Page: {state.page}
      <button onClick={() => dispatch({type: 'prev'})}>-</button>
      <button onClick={() => dispatch({type: 'next'})}>+</button>
    </>
  );
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It's usually better to avoid letting useEffect handle pagination so you can have full control of what's going on.

You could

```
  const [currentPage, setCurrentPage] = useState(0);
  const [lastPage, setLastPage] = useState(true);

  const fetchData = useCallback((page: number) => {
    yourFetchFunction(page).then((response) => {
      // By setting page here, you will update the page just if it works
      setCurrentPage(page);

      // If your endpoint returns last, you can also update it here
      setLastPage(response.last);

      // ... Do whatever you need with the response
    });
  }, []);

  // First run, that's why we have the useCallback
  useEffect(() => fetchData(0), [fetchData]);

  // To load the next page, we can simply fetch data passing the next page
  // State is going to be update if it succeeds. If it fails, "page is going to be reverted" (actually, not updated)
  const loadMore = () => {
    if (!lastPage) {
      fetchData(currentPage + 1);
    }
  };
```